# NullPointerException getting StringArray to String[]

Tags: android, arrays, string, arraylist, expandablelistadapter

Ok so i have 5 arrays all with 5 elements in them in my strings.xml file like so:

```
<string-array name="monday">
        <item>monday</item>
        <item>tuesday</item>
        <item>wednesday</item>
        <item>thursday</item>
        <item>friday</item>
    </string-array>
```

now i have a switch statement in my code that deppending on the button that they click will set one of these 5 arrays to my main array. however i have tried many differant ways but i still get null pointer exception on this line:

```
Days.masterarray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.monday);
```

also trued this but got the same result:

```
Days.setMasterarray(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.monday));
```

master array:

```
public static String[] masterarray = new String[] { "monday", "tuesday",
            "wednesday", "thursday", "friday" };
```

i have given it default values to begin with. now when i run the switch statement i get this:

```
03-19 13:43:23.555: WARN/System.err(1379): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-19 13:43:23.586: WARN/System.err(1379):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:81)
03-19 13:43:23.586: WARN/System.err(1379):     at schoolBook.Icestone.Days.setArray(Days.java:77)
03-19 13:43:23.595: WARN/System.err(1379):     at schoolBook.Icestone.SampleActivity.onCreate(SampleActivity.java:27)
03-19 13:43:23.605: WARN/System.err(1379):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
03-19 13:43:23.626: WARN/System.err(1379):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1700)
03-19 13:43:23.626: WARN/System.err(1379):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1577)
03-19 13:43:23.635: WARN/System.err(1379):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:130)
03-19 13:43:23.644: WARN/System.err(1379):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:342)
03-19 13:43:23.655: WARN/System.err(1379):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:680)
03-19 13:43:23.676: WARN/System.err(1379):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:349)
03-19 13:43:23.676: WARN/System.err(1379):     at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:239)
03-19 13:43:23.695: WARN/System.err(1379):     at schoolBook.Icestone.Days.onCreate(Days.java:32)
03-19 13:43:23.695: WARN/System.err(1379):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
03-19 13:43:23.695: WARN/System.err(1379):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1700)
03-19 13:43:23.716: WARN/System.err(1379):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1752)
03-19 13:43:23.716: WARN/System.err(1379):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-19 13:43:23.716: WARN/System.err(1379):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
03-19 13:43:23.735: WARN/System.err(1379):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-19 13:43:23.735: WARN/System.err(1379):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
03-19 13:43:23.744: WARN/System.err(1379):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
03-19 13:43:23.754: WARN/System.err(1379):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 13:43:23.754: WARN/System.err(1379):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
03-19 13:43:23.754: WARN/System.err(1379):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
03-19 13:43:23.775: WARN/System.err(1379):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
03-19 13:43:23.775: WARN/System.err(1379):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

any light on how to fix this would be much appreciated

Comment: I would try to do a project clean and rebuild. Sometimes R class doesn't get updated - at least with last SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think getResources might be null. Try either

- placing a breakpoint at that line and debug to see if it is null (if it is not null, then find what is null)
- using the context. ie.
  `mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.monday));`

Comment: Fixed thanks, as the switch statement was static i had to pass it context and then it worked.